# what is the advantage of ListSet or ListMap over Set and Map in Scala

Tags: scala

what is the advantage of ListSet or ListMap over Set and Map in Scala? Is it that ListSet and ListMap is an ordered collection compared to Set and Map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both of them use a List internally to represent the values.
This means that they will always keep the order in which the elements were inserted.

In Java there are collections called `LinkedHashMap` and `LinkedHashSet` which are very similar in nature.

However `ListMap` and `ListSet` incur O(n) complexity on operations such as `head`,  inserting or removing entries. Merely `last` and `init` are constant time operations.

For example:

```
scala> val x = Set(1,2,4,456,23,5,3)
scala> x.foreach(println)
5 1 456 2 3 23 4 3


scala> val y = ListSet(1,2,4,456,23,5,3)
scala> y.foreach(println)
3 5 23 456 4 2 1
```

Note that both `ListMap` and `ListSet` store their elements in  reversed insertion order.

Comment: They are not similar to java. Java `LinkedHashMap` and `LinkedHashSet` have constant time lookups. `LinkMap` and `LinkSet` lookups are linear.

Comment: I meant in regards to being backed by a List under the hood.

Comment: I know. But `LinkedHashMap` is NOT backed by a list. It's backed by the same hash structure as a regular map, but keeps a linked list on the side to keep track of the ordering.

Comment: I think, it may be useful to mention the linear lookup property in your answer. People tend to autmatically assume constant time lookups when they hear "map" ...

Comment: Agreed! Added it :)

Answer (score 0):

ListSet and ListMap now ensure insertion-order traversal (in 2.11.x, traversal was in reverse order), and their performance has been improved (#5103).

scala> val y = ListSet(1,2,4,456,23,5,3)

scala> y.foreach(println)

1
2
4
456
23
5
3